# How to open a specific viewpager tab on notification click android

Tags: android

Right now I am just opening an activity on notification click with extra data. From this activity I want to open a specific viewpager tab on click of notification data.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.fcmnotificationactivity);


     readMore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openACtivity);

     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}
public void OpenActivity() {

}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    finish();
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From where you are sending extra data with intent, also send position of the tab you want to click with intent and in your activity of tabs fetch this position in onCreate as below:

```
viewpager.setCurrentItem(getIntent().getIntExtra("position",DEFAULT_INT_VALUE));
```

Comment: from firebase messaging class on message received

Comment: private void sendNotification(NotificationData notificationData) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
      

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("title",notificationData.getTitle());
        bundle.putString("textMessage",notificationData.getTextMessage());
        bundle.putString("expiry_date",notificationData.getExpiry_date());

Comment: If you want to send it with intent write intent.putExtra("title",notificationData.getTitle());

Answer (score 0):

Create your view pager fragment like this

```
public class TabFragment extends BaseFragments {
private static int argument = 0;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TextView employeeReferralText;
Context context;
private static Bundle bundle;
private SetName setName;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

public static TabFragment newInstance(int arg, Bundle bundles) {
    TabFragment fragment = new TabFragment();
    argument = arg;
    bundle = bundles;
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab, container, false);

    try {
        context = getActivity();


        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        bundle = getArguments();
        setActionBar();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return view;
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    try {

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new FirstFragment(), "firstFragment");
        adapter.addFrag(new SecondFragment(),"secondFragment");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (argument == 0)
            ;
        else {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(argument, true);
            argument = 0;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();


    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        try {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

In on newIntent Of your Activity

@Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {

```
        if (intent != null) {
          replaceFragment(context,TabFragment.newInstance(0,new Bundle()));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```